# .htaccess RewriteRule won't work!

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, menu

I'm using php switch[_get] in my menu system to create url.com/?p=page and I'd like that to change into url.com/page.html. But I can't make it work, maybe some of you know the right settings for this.

I'm currently using this as .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^start(.*)\.html$ ?p=start$
```

Thank you!

**Update:**

I tried with the `$1` but still the url is: `?p=start` when I want it to be `/start.html`

Comment: Please add the URL *as you enter it into your browser* to the question.

Comment: well I simply enter url.com but since the menu only holds 7 links I want every link to be url.com/page instead of page.com/?p=page

Comment: That has nothing to do with the .htaccess file. You need to change the output of your menu code.

Comment: Well when I've googled rewriterule it looks like there's many out there who uses the same settings as I do. As php uses switch[_Get] to fetch ?p=x I want to remove that and also change the .php into .html. Maybe I should just change all the links into start.php etc and change from php to html in htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing the `$1`  in your last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^start(.*)\.html$ ?p=start$1
                                     ^^^^
```

**EDIT** After new information, try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1.html [L]
```

This captures the `p=` parameter from the querystring and uses it to rewrite to `page.html`

Comment: Hm I tried with the $1 but still the url is: ?p=start when I want it to be /start.html

Comment: @Jaoza Media So you want your user to enter `/start.html` and redirect internally to `?p=start`?  Please give an example of what the user enters vs exactly what is to be redirected internally.

Comment: @Michael sorry for my bad description :)

Basically I want the htaccess to redirect all urls from ?p=page to page.html, but since I already have static id's such as start/about/services/contact I want i.e ?p=services to be services.html.

Comment: @Jaoza Media If I understand correctly now, please try my edited information above.

Comment: @Michael sorry this gives internal server error. I'm not able to access any page except for url.com.

Comment: @Michael - I think the problem is that Jaoza tries to change the HTML output with the .htaccess.

Comment: @hakre Yeah, I'm having a difficult time understanding this.

Comment: @Michael - same for me. Looks like SE is sort of the next step after google because you can enter more text for a search query and get human-revisited answers :/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^start(.*)\.html$ ?p=start$1 [L]
```

See the one (1) at the end.

Comment: L = Last - Last Rule. [See docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), no other rule will be executed after this rule.

Answer (score 1):

htaccess works the other way around.

It makes things like `/start.html` proxy to `?p=start` however, you still have make the links themselves target `/start.html`.

So change all the `<a href="?p=start">` to `<a href="/start.html">`.

Comment: right now they're called start.php etc, but due to search engine optimization I want the urls to be in html.

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

R=301 is to change the url in the browser, but
you still need to update all links on the site:

`<a href="?p=start">` to `<a href="/start.html">`

Edit: Try the updated one (it has a ? after html)

Comment: change them to what? Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me start.html?p=start instead of just start.html